# On each submit to show a new random array class of random array subclass

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm creating a lorem ipsum app and I want to click on a button to generate random quotes from a random character. And there will be no mixing of quotes between characters. However, every time I click submit it only shows random quotes from the first character I list in my array. How can I fix this?

```
const aQuotes = require("./public/quotes/a");
const bQuotes = require("./public/quotes/b");
const cQuotes = require("./public/quotes/c");

const loremIpsum = new GenerateNewText();
function GenerateNewText(){}

GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
  const charQuotes =
  [
    aQuotes,
    bQuotes,
    cQuotes,
  ]
  for(var i = 0; i < charQuotes.length; i++){
    let randomSentence = charQuotes[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * charQuotes[i][Math.floor(Math.random())].length)]
    return randomSentence;
  }
}
```

When I run the example above, it'll show a random list of quotes stored in `aQuotes` with the word "undefined" sprinkled throughout. If I were to move `bQuotes` to the top of the array, then it will show random `bQuotes` only, also with the word "undefined". Why is it only showing the results of the first element in the array and why is "undefined" showing (i.e. `aQuotes`)?

```
const aQuotes = [
    "Lalalalalalalala.",
    "Blah blah blah blah.",
    "Blank Blank Blank Blank Blank." 
]

module.exports = aQuotes;
```

I tried doing `charQuotes[i][Math.floor(Math.random())].length * charQuotes[i][Math.floor(Math.random())].length` thinking that it will first randomize the `charQuotes` array and then randomize the individual `a/b/cQuotes` array but it ended up returning a block of the number 169. Other "fixes" I've attempted resulted in paragraphs of all `undefined` text, paragraphs of all `NaN`, or showing all the quotes for all the characters with the word "undefined" interjected here and there.

How can I randomize the charQuotes array AND the content in my `a/b/cQuotes`  array with every click? And get rid of the weird "undefined" texts that come up?

I am using Node and Express.

Comment: _"However, every time I click submit it only shows random quotes from the first character I list in my array."_ When `i` is `0` the value is returned from the function at `return randomSentence;`

Comment: Okay I get what you mean and set this instead
`for(var i; i < charQuotes.length; i++){
    let randomSentence = charQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * charQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random())].length)]
    return randomSentence;
  }` but am just getting blocks of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.map()` `charQuotes` and return a pseudo random value from each input array, and further `.sort()` the resulting array pseudo randomly

```js
const getRandomSentence = () => {
  const charQuotes =
  [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
  ];
  const r = charQuotes.map(arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)])
            .sort(_ => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return r.join(" ")
}

console.log(getRandomSentence());
```

Comment: Hi there, this works but again it's showing quotes from every character when I only want the quotes from one character, but the one character is randomly selected.

Comment: What do you mean by _"quotes from one character"_? From a single array?

Comment: Please see the clarification and Harry Potter example I commented in Hugo Silva's answer.

Comment: @TJS13 Am not familiar with any of the characters mentioned (havn't watched any of those films) though get the gist of the functionality. Given the code at the question there are no names for the arrays, the arrays are only elements (indexes) within an array `charQuotes`. Therefore you can select which index should be mapped and use the same code at the answer and bracket notation to select the appropriate or random index `const r = charQuotes[index].map()` or `const r = charQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * charQuotes.length)].map()`. To have a named reference for arrays you can use an object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` loop. You are entering a loop only to return in the first iteration. That is why you always get the first array of quotes.

```
GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
  const allQuotes =
  [
    aQuotes,
    bQuotes,
    cQuotes,
  ]
  const characterQuotes = allQuotes[ Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuotes.length) ]
  return characterQuotes[ Math.floor(Math.random() * characterQuotes.length) ]
}
```

---

If you want to generate quotes from the same character, you will need to hold the character info in a variable outside the function scope, or in the object instance like the following example:

```
GenerateNewText.prototype.allQuotes = [
  aQuotes,
  bQuotes,
  cQuotes,
]
GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
  if ( !this.characterQuotes ) {
    this.characterQuotes = this.allQuotes[ Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuotes.length) ]
  }
  return this.characterQuotes[ Math.floor(Math.random() * characterQuotes.length) ]
}
```

Comment: This works but it returns quotes from every character, when I want it to only return quotes from one character, but for that one character to be randomly selected each time I click submit?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want exactly. Do you want to generate several quotes from one random character?

Comment: Let's say we're talking about generating Harry Potter quotes. So I have an array of charQuotes which links to files for Harry, Hermione, and Ron quotes separately. The quotes are also in an array. See my OP for the setup. I want to configure a system where each time I click submit, it will pick a random character (i.e., Harry, Ron, or Hermione) and show the random quotes I have in their files. So if Harry is selected it will only show quotes in Harry files, not in Hermione nor Ron. The current set up you provided will generate random quotes from all three characters. Does this make sense?

Comment: It does. Check the update. Just to clarify, the example uses prototype because it is what you already have, but I would probably do it differently. I would break things up into different functions, and call them as appropriate. Hard to tell without knowing yours project in depth. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks for trying and for the advice. I'll go and tinker around with it some more.